# VLOOKUP formula and/or VBA code to automaticall search files named by date

Tags: excel, vba

I submit weekly reports using Excel 2013, in which the file name includes the current date as part of its name. For example, "02.16.15 Load Board." I'm trying to create a VLOOKUP formula that will compare task due dates between the current week's file and the previous week's file automatically. An example of the formula I last used was:

=+VLOOKUP(B560,'[02.09.15 Load Board.xlsm]Master Sheet'!$B$4:$P$953,6,FALSE).

comparing "02.16.15 Load Board" with "02.09.15 Load Board" for differences in task due dates.

This worked fine. But is there a VLOOPUP formula or VBA code that will automate this according to the name of the report date? Is it possible to subtract 7 days in the name of the report to automatically choose the report that was 7 days earlier? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ert()
Dim wbname As String
wbname = InputBox("What is the name of the outdated report file?") '"02.16.15 Load Board.xlsm"
wbyear = CLng(2000 + Mid(wbname, 7, 2))
wbmonth = CLng(Left(wbname, 2))
wbday = CLng(Mid(wbname, 4, 2))

datemod = DateValue(wbday & "/" & wbmonth & "/" & wbyear)
datemod = DateAdd("d", +7, datemod)

wbyear = Right(CStr(DatePart("yyyy", datemod)), 2)
    If Len(wbyear) < 2 Then wbyear = "0" & wbyear
wbmonth = DatePart("m", datemod)
    If Len(wbmonth) < 2 Then wbmonth = "0" & wbmonth
wbday = DatePart("d", datemod)
    If Len(wbday) < 2 Then wbday = "0" & wbday
x = wbmonth & "." & wbday & "." & wbyear & Right(wbname, Len(wbname) - 8)
ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="" & wbname & "", Replacement:="" & x & "", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: How about the VLOOKUP formula placement - sorry, what I meant to ask.

Comment: This should work just fine. Make sure the workbook where the new formulae will refer to is **open** and this should do the trick just fine. the wbname goes without extension, just as it goes in your formula (which you'd like to replace). In this case it's _02.09.15 Load Board_ .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to insert the filename. Then this snipplet will transform your data into actual dates that can in turn be used to create the actual one week before's filename (regardless of month or year change).
P.S. "ww" is for the weak.
P.P.S. smartass disclaimer: will only work from Jan 8, 2000 to Dec 31, 2,<strike>9</strike> 099.

```
Sub ert()
Dim wbname As String
'wbname = InputBox("What is the name of the report file?") '"02.16.15 Load Board.xlsm"
wbyear = CLng(2000 + Mid(wbname, 7, 2))
wbmonth = CLng(Left(wbname, 2))
wbday = CLng(Mid(wbname, 4, 2))

datemod = DateValue(wbday & "/" & wbmonth & "/" & wbyear)
datemod = DateAdd("d", -7, datemod)

wbyear = Right(CStr(DatePart("yyyy", datemod)), 2)
    If Len(wbyear) < 2 Then wbyear = "0" & wbyear
wbmonth = DatePart("m", datemod)
    If Len(wbmonth) < 2 Then wbmonth = "0" & wbmonth
wbday = DatePart("d", datemod)
    If Len(wbday) < 2 Then wbday = "0" & wbday
x = wbmonth & "." & wbday & "." & wbyear & Right(wbname, Len(wbname) - 8)
'MsgBox (x)
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding inserting the filename, you mean into the input box, correct? That's a great idea to use the input box. Thanks! I'm not sure what "x" is though. Sorry, I'm still pretty new to all this.

Comment: BTW, I failed to mention that this code is awesome!

Comment: It's based on a generic solution, you can use wbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name too

Comment: x could be wbname2, it's the output name

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much. The only last question I have is that I don't need to actually create the previous week's file; I need to access/open what's already created in the same folder. Then I need to do the VLOOKUP, or something, to compare the due dates column of both files to be sure the dates were not changed in the latter file from the former file. What you have so far is so great! Thank you, and thank you for helping with this one last question.

Comment: I think it shoud be like    
YourCells.FormulaR1C1 = "=+VLOOKUP(RC2,'[" & x & "]Master Sheet'!R4C2:R953C16,6,FALSE)"   
where x is the output of my sniplet and the range YourCells is a range you'll need to specify either with Cells or Range method.   
P.S. I recommend using a named range instead of B4 to P953 as the number of rows seems to be variable.

Comment: Alternatively you can "upgrade" your outdated filename. In this case you'll copy the outdated "02.02.15 Load Board" and then run my sniplet, insert the name but with datemod = DateAdd("d", **+7**, datemod) and then make a replacement like ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="" & wbname & "", Replacement:="" & x & "", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Comment: The YourCells.Formula is great with B4:P953. Prefect! Can you just tell me where in the code this should go?

Comment: **Cells.Replace What:="" & wbname & "", Replacement:="" & x & "", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False** needs to run on each sheet of the upgraded workbook that has the formula you want to change.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks for your patience. It's perfect.